# jquery gettime always make the time before 4 hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, timezone, flot

This is my code

```
minVal = new Date(2014, 2, 2, 08, 00, 00);
maxVal = new Date(2014, 2, 2, 20, 00, 00);
```

I want to draw a chart using flot.

this is my code:

```
chartOptions = {
               xaxis: {
                   min: minVal.getTime(),
                   max: maxVal.getTime(),
                                  },
```

ofc I am just showing you the relevant code not all my code in order to make the question clear.

#### The problem

as you see, the min val is 8 AM and the max is 8 PM (20)

but the chart draw values from 4 AM to 4 PM (16)

even when I keep changing the values. always there are 4 hours before the real time.

help me please?

if you need more code, kindly tell me.

#### Update 1

after the comment from the user `@monkeyinsight`, he/she inspires me to ask which time zoom is the default in jquery please?

Comment: use `setTimezone` on date object to make it equal

Comment: @monkeyinsight yes how please?

Comment: your local timezone is default :) just create your date as `new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second))`

Comment: @monkeyinsight I am developing a project to work with `azt` time zone. is your comment will be the saame please? or I have to do something like `new Date(Date.azt..)`

Comment: same, UTC date is universal, you can add hours to represent needed timezone

Comment: @monkeyinsight will test it and update you

Comment: Do you see this behavior on your local dev system or when you deploy your application to a server which runs in a different TZ?

Comment: @monkeyinsight fascinating, it works, it really works :) :) please write an answer to accept it. 1M thanks

Comment: @TJ- it is a complicated issue. the client, who will use the application, is in different zone that the server. (there are 1.5 hours different between them). sure I didn't deploy the application yet, it is in the development stage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create dates as `new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)` and then you can manipulate timezones by adding needed amount of hours to date object